# Using Enum to Handle String literals

Tags: java, performance, enum

I have a java component that was using a lot of string literals that I need to make comparisons on and return booleans based on these comparisons.

In order to make the code more robust I externalized these strings first as class constants, then after other classes started to use these constants I had to separate them to decrease the dependency between the classes.

Knowing that the best practice is not to use variable-classes dedicated for string for many reasons, and since I am using Java 6, I decided to go for enums. below is the implementation that I had in mind

```
public enum SecurityClassification {
    SENSITIVE("Sensitive"), HIGHLY_SENSITIVE("Highly Sensitive"), PUBLIC("Public"), INTERNAL("Internal");

    private String value;

    private SecurityClassification(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean hasValue(String param) {
        return value.equalsIgnoreCase(param);
    }

    public static SecurityClassification enumForValue(String param){
        for (SecurityClassification securityClassification : SecurityClassification.values()) {
            if(securityClassification.getValue().equals(param)){
                return securityClassification;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I was wondering specifically about the enumForValue method, is this an optimal solution? is there any other better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine overall, but...

#### A few pointers

1. You should make `private String value` `final` too though, to clearly indicate that they cannot be modified after instantiation.
2. One thing to note for `values()` is that it always returns a new array, so for that reason, sometimes it may be recommended to also construct a lookup `Map<String, SecurityClassification>` to avoid the extra arrays creation.
3. Also, is it really OK to just return `null` if an invalid security classification is specified here? Depending on your implementation, you may want to consider whether you should `throw` an `IllegalArgumentException` here to have a slightly better modelling of such cases.
4. How is `hasValue()` used? In fact, can it be used in `enumForValue()` for a case-insensitive comparison?
5. Finally, `enumForValue()` may seem like a mouthful, you can consider a shorter name like `of()`. The other thing to consider is that you don't really need to express that it's an `enum` this method is returning.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I have updated the code and added static initializer as the values will not be changed in run-time. The throughput of the code is better than before.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your given advice I'd recommend that your enumerated values have their own distinct lines. It will help extensibility, readability, and eliminate horizontal scrolling.

```
public enum SecurityClassification {
    SENSITIVE("Sensitive"),
    HIGHLY_SENSITIVE("Highly Sensitive"),
    PUBLIC("Public"),
    INTERNAL("Internal");
//...
}
```

That pattern is conventional, and makes it easy to alter values, or add a classification exclusive method or constructor.

Another note is that if your values are consistently named according to your current pattern you may consider foregoing the additional variable and simply altering `toString`:

```
public enum SecurityClassification {
    SENSITIVE,
    HIGHLY_SENSITIVE,
    PUBLIC,
    INTERNAL;

    @Override
    public String toString() { // or keep getValue() with this implementation
        return name().charAt(0) + name.substring(1).replace('_', ' ');
    }

    // ...
}
```

You may note, however, that wouldn't retain the capitalization of the proceeding words in a string value. You can modify the method to consider those cases, if desirable. e.g.

```
public String getValue() {
  StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
  for (String word : name().split("_")) {
    value.append(' ').append(word.charAt(0)).append(word.substring(1).toLowerCase());
  }

  return value.substring(1);
}
```

but then it may arguably become 'costly' and it becomes preferrable to simply store the value, maintaining a constructor for the longer named values.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code based on @H.J.K comments. my updates included setting the value field as final and changed the name of enumForValue() to be of() to enhance code readability.

Most importantly added a static initializer that fills the enum values in a Map to cut the time needed every time to call enum values() method and also the loop used to query passed.

The throughput of the code was enhanced by 3 folds (I am using the the system time method which I know can wildly vary between executions, I did 10 runs each and collected the average).

I am adding the code below to indicate the changes added

```
package com.ibm.ecm.cetest;

import java.util.HashMap;

public enum SecurityClassification {
    SENSITIVE("Sensitive"), HIGHLY_SENSITIVE("Highly Sensitive"), PUBLIC("Public"), INTERNAL("Internal");

    //static map to hold the enums and their values as keys
    final static HashMap<String, SecurityClassification> securityClassifications = new HashMap<String, SecurityClassification>();

    //This will initialize the array so that it won't be called every time in of() method
    static {
        for (SecurityClassification securityClassification : SecurityClassification.values()) {
            securityClassifications.put(securityClassification.getValue(), securityClassification);
        }
    }

    private final String value;

    private SecurityClassification(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean hasValue(String param) {
        return value.equalsIgnoreCase(param);
    }

    //The method has a new descriptive name, and the Map is now used to query the item   
    public static SecurityClassification of(String param) {
        if (securityClassifications.containsKey(param)) {
            return securityClassifications.get(param);
        } else {
            //Instead of returning null, an exception is thrown if no key was found and hence no corresponding enum
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid security classification: " + param);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @H.J.K Thanks for your help, please feel free to make any comments you might find

Comment: Usually, you can post this as a new question (and delete this answer). :)